# What is Smarter flow analysis in Dart?

Tags: dart

From [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#definite-assignment-analysis):

```
int tracingFibonacci(int n) {
  final int result; // Error
  if (n < 2) {
    result = n; // Error
  } else {
    result = tracingFibonacci(n - 2) + tracingFibonacci(n - 1); // Error
  }

  print(result);
  return result;
}
```

> This would be an error since the result variable is final but has no initializer. With the smarter flow analysis under null safety, this program is fine. The analysis can tell that result is definitely initialized exactly once on every control flow path, so the constraints for marking a variable final are satisfied.

I'm getting compile time error, but the docs speak something else. So, what's "Smarter flow analysis", how do I enable such feature?

Comment: Also a problem with Dart VM version 2.10.0-7.0.dev (running in NNBD mode). I think you should create a bug report about this. A reason could be this feature has yet to be implemented... but I can't find any traces on the bug tracker about this feature.

Comment: Found the following on the issue tracker: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38237 , https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/946 ,  https://github.com/dart-lang/language/pull/1091 . I am still trying to read though it all.

Comment: Ok, I think the conclusion is that this part of the NNBD feature has yet to be landed in the SDK since it is still a discussion in the language issue tracker. So I guess the "Understanding null safety" article has been written based on how the NNBD feature are properly going to be and not based on the current state of the main branch of the SDK.

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you so much for going through all that, to be honest, I don't like reading theories :) So, should I delete this question now or will you write it as answer?

Comment: Well, I am not 100% sure about the answer so I am not going to post any. You can either delete it or hope one from the Dart team is going to post an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what's "Smarter flow analysis"?

These links explain something similar to that. Dart implementation may be based on it. I quote some useful information in this post so as to save someone from clicking the links.

> Data-flow analysis is a technique for gathering information about the possible set of values calculated at various points in a computer program. A program's control flow graph (CFG) is used to determine those parts of a program to which a particular value assigned to a variable might propagate. The information gathered is often used by compilers when optimizing a program. A canonical example of a data-flow analysis is reaching definitions.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis

> Data Flow Analysis is a type of static analysis. The goal of static analysis is to reason about program behavior at compile-time, before ever running the program. The goal of dynamic analysis, in contrast, is to reason about program behavior at run-time. Data Flow Analysis typically operates over a Control-Flow Graph (CFG), a graphical representation of a program.
>
> Consider, for example, the following Java code:
>
> ```
>    public String badCode(int x) {
>        String y = null;
>        if (x > 0) {
>            y = "more";
>        } else if (x < 0) {
>            y = "less";
>        }
>        return y.toUpperCase();
>    }
> ```
>
> We can represent this by the following CFG:
> [image]
> Using this CFG, we can reason globally (from the start to the exit of the CFG) about the behavior of a program by reasoning locally (at a single statement or sequence of statements without branches) about facts. For example, we may want to know if there are any possible null-pointer exceptions in our program. We can do this by reasoning locally about the definitions in our CFG. We know program point 1 assigns null to a variable, and we also know this value is overwritten at points 3 and 5. Using this information, we can determine whether the definition at point 1 may reach program point 6 where it's used. If it can, we have a possible null-pointer exception.

- https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse401/16wi/sections/section8/dfa.html